# Approximation of the falling factorial

Tags: approximation, factorial

I found an approximation of the **falling factorial** for $k\ll N$:
$$
(N)_k = N(N-1)\ldots(N-k+1)\approx N^k
$$
Any idea how to get it?

Comment: $N = N$, $N -1 \approx N$, $N-2\approx N$, ..., $N-k+1 \approx N$

Comment: ....I thought at the same thing initially, but I thought it was too trivial.. thanks a lot ;-)

Comment: As far as $k$ is fixed, it is easy to check these expressions are *asymptotically equivalent* (which is is not exactly an approximation, a notion which  is not mathematically defined – you'd have to give  a degree of precision.

Comment: Intuitively, as $N \to \infty,$ the effect of a **fixed** value $k$, re the difference (for example) between $N$ and $N+ 1 - k$ becomes trivial.  This is the same idea that player3236 just comment/expressed.

Comment: Thanks to everyone! Yes, $k$ is fixed..... I feel quite dumb hahaha :-)

Answer (score 2):

Factoring (N)_k = N^k (1- 1/N)(1-2/N)...[1-(k-1)/N)]. Then since k<<N, k/N-> 0. Therefore, (N)_k ~ N^k (1)^k = N^k.

Comment: Good, but please use math formatting as described by https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(N)_{k} = \frac{N!}{(N-k)!}$. From there, we may use Stirling's Approximation:

$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}n^{n}e^{-n}$:

Subtituting:

$(N)_{k} \approx \frac{\sqrt{2\pi N}N^{N}e^{-N}}{\sqrt{2\pi (N-k)}(N-k)^{N-k}e^{k-N}}$

$(N)_{k}\approx \frac{N^{N}}{(N-k)^{N-k}}\sqrt{\frac{N}{N-k}}e^{-k}$

$\boxed{(N)_{k}\approx \frac{N^{N+\frac{1}{2}}}{(N-k)^{N-k + \frac{1}{2}}}e^{-k}}$

Comment: Thanks Joshua, but I did not get the point where $(N)_k \approx N^k$ ?